# Script for interactivity in bookdown::bs4_book vs bookdown::gitbook

Tags: r, rstudio, bookdown, gitbook

I am interested in incorporating a simple, radio button-style quiz in a bookdown::bs4_book environment. I have a minimal example below that works when I specify bookdown::gitbook in the header, but stops working when I choose bookdown::bs4_book. Does anyone have any ideas how to get this working with the bookdown::bs4_book option?

(note: the .Rmd code below needs to be saved as "index.Rmd" in order to be knitted using bs4_book.)

Thank you,

Luke

````
    --- 
    title: "formative_test"
    site: bookdown::bookdown_site
    output:
      # bookdown::gitbook:
      bookdown::bs4_book:
        css: [style.css, font-awesome.min.css]
        repo: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo
    ---
    
    # Chapter 1
    
    ```{r results = "asis", echo = FALSE}
    question <- function(question, distractors, correct, no, fb = "", print_question = TRUE){
      allanswers <- c(distractors, correct)[sample.int(length(distractors)+1)]
      correctanswer <- which(allanswers == correct)
      answercode <- paste0(sapply(1:length(allanswers), function(i){
        x <- allanswers[i]
        paste0('<div class="radio">\n  <label>\n    <input type="radio" name="question', no, '" id="opt', i,'" value="', i, '" onchange="check_answer', no, '()">\n    ', x, '\n  </label>\n</div>')
      }), collapse = "\n\n")
    
      out <- paste0(question, "\n\n", answercode,
                 '<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample', no,'">
      <div class="card card-body" id="answerFeedback', no, '">
      </div>
    </div>',
                 paste0('<script type="text/javascript">
    function check_answer', no, '()
    {
        var radioButtons', no, ' = document.getElementsByName("question', no, '");
        document.getElementById("answerFeedback', no, '").innerHTML = "Try selecting an answer!!";
        for(var i = 0; i < radioButtons', no, '.length; i++)
        {
            if(radioButtons', no, '[i].checked == true)
            {
                var feedback', no, ' = "<p style=\'color:red\'>Wrong', ifelse(fb == "", ".", paste0("; ", fb)),  '</p>";
                if(radioButtons', no, '[i].value == "', correctanswer, '") {
                  feedback', no, ' = "<p style=\'color:green\'>Correct!</p>"
                }
                document.getElementById("answerFeedback', no, '").innerHTML = feedback', no, ';
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    '))
      if(print_question){
        cat(out)
      } else {
        return(out)
      }
    }
    
    questionnaire <- function(x, shuffle = TRUE, print_question = TRUE){
      if(inherits(x, "character")) x <- read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")
      if(!all(names(x) == c("question", "distractors", "correct", "fb"))){
        stop("Incorrect column names")
      }
      if(shuffle){
        x <- x[sample.int(nrow(x)), ]
      }
      out <- ""
      for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
        out <- paste0(out,
                      "**Question ",
                      i,
                      ":**\n",
                      question(question = x$question[i],
                               distractors = eval(parse(text = x$distractors[i])),
                               correct = x$correct[i],
                               no = i,
                               fb = ifelse(is.na(x$fb[i]), "", x$fb[i]),
                               print_question = FALSE),
                      "\n\n"
                      )
      }
      if(print_question){
        cat(out)
      } else {
        return(out)
      }
    }
    
    questionnaire(
      x = data.frame(
        question = "True or False?",
        distractors = "\"FALSE\"",
        correct = TRUE,
        fb = "here is some example feedback"
      )
    )
````